# Why Singleton is implemented in very basic way in Optional class in JDK

Tags: java-8, singleton, option-type

While learning Singleton pattern, I learned that Singleton pattern with the only private constructor and static method is not safe Singleton as it will break in a multithreaded environment. There are multiple approaches like two-way locking etc to prevent that.

I am curious what would have been requirement for having very basic Singleton implementation in java.util.Optional class.

Comment: The Singleton pattern is only unsafe (breaking in multithreaded environments) if you try to lazily create the Singleton. If you eagerly construct your Singleton it is always safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different reasons, each of them alone would be sufficient to make the `Optional.empty()` thread safe:

- the `static final` field is immediately assigned with the instance, hence, the assignment will be made within the class initializer, which is safe, if the initializer doesn’t call any other code that will access the static variables of this class
- `Optional` objects are immutable and the only instance field is `final`, hence, does benefit from the special safe publication guaranty of the JMM, as long as the instance does not escape during construction, which is the case here
- in the case of the empty `Optional`, the assignment in the constructor doesn’t actually change the value. The result state is identical to the default value for this field, i.e. `null`, hence, observing an uninitialized state of this object would not make any difference to its initialized state.

As said, each point alone would be sufficient for `Optional.empty()` to be thread safe.

Generally, the first point is the recommended way of implementing singletons instead of double checked locking and similar, as class initialization is already lazy and safe with the least overhead possible.